# C program crashes after freeing the pointers in an array of char *

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm a student learning C and I was puttering around with arrays of strings and malloc().

I have the following code that is supposed to load an array of strings (statically created) with dynamically created strings (please forgive / correct me if my terminology does not align with the code I have).

The problem is, once I go to free that memory, I get the following error: `free(): invalid pointer`

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RAM_SIZE 5

char* ram [RAM_SIZE];
int next_free_cell = 0;

void freeAndNullRam(){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < RAM_SIZE ; i++){
      printf("%d\n", i);
        free(ram[i]);
        ram[i] = NULL;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  for (int i= 0; i < RAM_SIZE; i++){
    ram[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*)*5);
    ram[i] = "aaaa";
  } 
  for (int i= 0; i < RAM_SIZE; i++){
    int empty = (ram[i] ==NULL);
    if(!empty){
      printf("%s\n", ram[i]);
    }
      
  }
  freeAndNullRam();
  for (int i= 0; i < RAM_SIZE; i++){
    int empty = (ram[i] ==NULL);
    printf("%d\n", empty);
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

I know the issue is definitely in the `freeAndNullRam()` function (obviously), but I don't understand why. My understanding is that at compile time, an array of 5 pointers to char arrays is created, but to actually fill the cells of the array, I need to `malloc` them some memory. Why does the program complain when I free the pointers in the array, but not when I give them memory?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to `NULL`. Just `free()`. Once you `free()` something it's dead, like a ghost, and you should never touch it. Use-after-free bugs are harsh.

Comment: Tip: If you have it, use `strdup()`.

Comment: @tadman I know I don't need to `NULL`, strictly speaking, but this is a component of a larger project I am working on, for which null entries in the array are used for something.

Comment: Tip: Name variables with meaningful names, not random junk like `ram` which is so vague as to be meaningless. Better choices are like `names` or `entries`.

Comment: If that's the case, consider calling it `clear()` where it not only wipes down the array with `NULL` values, but releases any allocated memory. A name that's too literal confuses the purpose. Like `addOneToX()` is really odd, but `increment()` is easily understood. Employ the *Principle of Least Surprise*.

Comment: @tadman thanks again for the help, I guess I should have taken away the parts of the code that are for other things. This is for a class in which we are supposed to simulate an OS, which requires a 'ram' data structure. Hence the name.

Comment: If this is for a course then do whatever you have to do to survive it. Just remember what they teach and what you should do are often completely orthogonal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ram[i] = "aaaa";` reassigns the pointers at `a[i]` to point to static memory, discarding the result of `malloc`. Later on you pass those pointers to `free`, which fails because they were not the result of an `*alloc` function.

Use [`strcpy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to instead copy the string from static memory into your allocated destination.

```
strcpy(a[i], "aaaa")
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a reworked version of your code to be more idiomatic C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Create an array of arbitrary size
char* alloc_array(size_t size) {
  // calloc() will give you a pre-zeroed (NULL) allocation, malloc() may not
  return calloc(size, sizeof(char*));
}

// Clears out all entries in the array, leaving only NULL
void clear_array(char* array, size_t size) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    // free(NULL) doesn't do anything, and is easier than a test
    free(array[i]);
    array[i] = NULL;
  }
}

// Clears, then frees the array
void free_array(char* array, size_t size) {
  clear_array(array, size);
  free(array);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  // Whenever possible use local variables, not global variables
  size_t size = 5;
  char* entries = alloc_array(size);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    // Make a copy with strdup() so this can be released with free()
    // later on. A string like "..." is static, it was never allocated.
    entries[i] = strdup("aaaa");
  } 

  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // Express conditions in the if statment directly
    if (entries[i] != NULL) {
      printf("%s\n", ram[i]);
    }
  }
  
  clear_array(entries);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", entries[i] != NULL);
  }

  // Don't forget to release any allocated memory.
  free_array(entries);

  return 0;
}
```

There's a lot of bad habits in your original code you should work to expunge as quickly as possible so these things don't take root. In particular, global variables are a huge problem that need to be avoided.

One thing to remember is unless something was explicitly allocated with `malloc()` or a variant like `calloc()`, or was given to your code with an understanding that it was allocated in such a fashion, you should not call `free()` on it.

Not every pointer was allocated dynamically, and not every dynamically allocated pointer was allocated with `malloc()`. Some C code can be very confusing as a result of this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestions and reworking of the code. I will take the suggestions to heart! I certainly feel the need to get rid of bad habits.

Answer (score -1):

C's syntax strongly suggests that `"aaaa"` is a "string". People even talk of this syntax that way: they call it "strings". But `"aaaa"` is nothing such. It's the unfortunately named string literal, which is *not* a string - neither in C nor in C++. A `char *` is not a string either - it's a pointer-typed value. It's used to represent strings, but itself is *not* a string - not even close.

You have *quite reasonably* expected that `"aaaa"` might behave like any other rvalue of the "obvious" type. Alas, while `1` is an integer literal of type `int`, `"aaaa"` is a string literal of a pointer type `const char *` - its value is not a string, but a pointer!

It's as if when you wrote `42`, C gave you a `const int *` pointing to `42`. That's what "string" literals do. That's the awfully deplorable side of C :(

In C++, there actually is a string type (`std::string`), and you can even write literals of that type with a new syntax introduced in C++11: `"aaaa"s` is an rvalue* of type `std::string`, and you can assign them exactly as you would expect of any other value type like `int`.

Since you're already thinking a bit like in C++, perhaps you can investigate that language next. It takes much less effort to do plenty of basic things in C++ compared to C.

*technically rvalue reference